# Как преобразовать данные из формата json в массив?

Tags: массивы, php, json

Как преобразовать данные из формата json в массив?

Comment: Возможно, [это][1] поможет.


  [1]: http://bit.ly/YFVnvE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[json-decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) - эта функция вам поможет.
Второй (необязательный) параметр в функции можете выставить в true для того, чтобы получился ассоциативный массив.